# MySql SELECT with Joins and conditions statement

Tags: mysql, join, coalesce

I have three tables

```
TABLE `courses` (
  id                int         NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title             varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  duration          int         NOT NULL,
  theme             varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  students_quantity int         NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
TABLE `users` (
  id       int         NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  email    varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  status   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  role_id  int         NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES `roles` (id)
);
TABLE `teachers_courses` (
  teacher_id int NOT NULL,
  course_id  int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (teacher_id, course_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES `users` (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES `courses` (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How can I get get courses.* and `users.name AS teacher` for this course, and if I have not `course_id` and `teacher_id` for this course in `teachers_courses` I'll get 'none' in `teacher`?

Comment: I'm sorry, its my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` to combine your data following primary key - foreign key path.
Function `coalesce()` would return the second argument, if the first one evaluates to `NULL`.

```
select c.*, coalesce(u.name, 'none') as teacher
from courses c
left join teachers_courses tc on c.id = tc.course_id
left join users u on tc.teacher_id = u.id
order by c.id
```

Since there can be multiple teachers for each course, the only case in which you would get `'none'` as teacher value would be if there is no teacher assigned for a course (not even one). If there is more than one teacher, there will be as many rows in the output as there are teachers for each course, thus I included `ORDER BY` to sort the result properly.

If you need to view the data for only one course, include a WHERE condition like this:

```
-- ... Above SQL here ...
WHERE c.id = ?
```